# jQuery - IF height is greater than 2 separate divs

Tags: jquery

Ok, so I asked a question earlier but didn't get the desired effect. As a result I've decided to tackle it in another way...

I'm trying to get the container to increase in height if either (or both) of the 2 panels are expanded.

```
var content = $("#content_container");  
var childaHeight = $('#news_events_panel').height();
var childbHeight = $('#headteachers_panel').height();

    if (content < childaHeight, childbHeight) {
        $(content).css("height", 657 + "px");
    }
```

This is working fine and increases the height of the container to 657px when the panels are open.

The tricky bit is the next bit...

The user can open both panels individually and the problem I'm having is that the container returns to `auto` height when the user closes only one of them. I need the container to return to `auto` ONLY if both panels are closed.

```
if (content > childaHeight & childbHeight) {
        $(content).css("height", "auto");
}
```

Basically, I need this 2nd script to read "If content is greater than childaHeight AND childbHeight, return to "auto". If not, keep height.

There's probably an easy solution, but I'm very very new to this and not really clued up on jQuery functions.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators

Comment: `if( a, b )` is syntactically correct but probably doesn't do what you assume it does.

Comment: @Juhana - comparing a jQuery object to an integer probably does'nt do much good either ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add them together I suppose :

```
if ( content.height() > (childaHeight + childbHeight) ) {
        content.css("height", "auto");
}
```

Comment: Just tried this and it didn't work..
Would it help to see the actual website?